# Help planning for an update to my app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am planning to release version 1.0 of my app now. I plan to release 1.1 in the next 2-3 months.

What are the things I need to take care of now for the initial release?

Also what should I select as SKU Number and Bundle ID in iTunes Connect for submitting 1.0?

Comment: I hope my question is clear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version numbers in software are completely arbitrary. Usually, you have a *major* version and a *minor* version. Consider the version "1.2". It's version one of the software and there have been two minor updates since the original release. (Note that this is subjective because it could *technically* be version 3 - where each release is a version change.)

You should not release a second version just for the sake of pushing an update. Generally, an update contains a bug fix or a feature enhancement. (For example, I made a game called "[Nippon](http://itunes.com/apps/nippon)". I'm updating it to have a new user interface on the iPad as well as fixing bugs. In contrast to this, consider another update I made to another app, which I just changed the icon. See the difference?)

As far as when to release your app, that is totally up to you. You don't need all of the features right away, but make sure that those that you do put out are completely implemented. *Don't rush to put out something with features that are incomplete.* Users will hate you for it. Instead, choose a core group of features that *are* your app. Make those work really well and then work on other things for the next version.

Here's a related excerpt from the [Apple Developer Resources "submission tips" section (requires login)](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/submission/tips.html):

> The two most common reasons for application rejection are issues with core functionality and crashing. Core functionality encompasses the belief that customers rightfully expect all the features described in the marketing text and release notes to work as described, and likewise that all the buttons and menu items within the application will be fully functional (i.e., no grayed out buttons or notifications that a feature will be implemented later). Before you submit your app for approval, make sure that every aspect of your application is fully functional and that the marketing text and release notes correspond to the end user experience.
>
> Also, make sure you thoroughly test your application on iPhone and iPod touch in addition to the iPhone Simulator. A large percentage of applications are rejected due to various types of crashes, including crashes on launch, which would have been found and dealt with if they'd been tested on an actual device. Don't skip that step in the development process.

Make sure that your app works and works as advertised. That should be your goal for version 1.

As far as SKU and bundle ID:

- SKU is supposed to be a four letter code, representing your app. In the old iTunes connect, you would see your SKU represent your downloads. I just checked and it seems that they print out the entire name of your app. However, just to illustrate, a valid SKU for Nippon would be **NPPN**. (I actually use that one.)
- Your Bundle ID should be a reversed domain name. For example, com.mosheberman.myapp could be a bundle ID for my app. You don't have to actually own the domain name, by the way. For Nippon, I used **com.yetanotheriphoneapp.nippon**.

Hope this helps.